# Picking out and showing only the highest value from one column based on three columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hei!

I have searched everywhere but cannot find the correct way to select only the highest result per student inside the same topic. So studentnr is the ID of the student in the table, emnekode is the topic code and karakter is result with A as highest and F as lowest.

Any suggestions to how I can make it work? I would appreciate it.

Here is the code so far with output under:

```
SELECT Eksamensresultat.*, Emnenavn, Studiepoeng
FROM Eksamensresultat, Emne
WHERE Eksamensresultat.Emnekode = Emne.Emnekode 
ORDER BY RIGHT (Eksamensresultat.Emnekode, 4) ASC;
```

I want the output to be like this (except result B since A is higher for that student):

[image: Output (picture)]

Here is the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Emne
(
Emnekode CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Emnenavn CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
Studiepoeng DECIMAL(3, 1),
CONSTRAINT EmnekodePK PRIMARY KEY(Emnekode)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Eksamen
(
Emnekode CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Dato DATE NOT NULL,
Romnr CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT EksamenPK PRIMARY KEY(Dato,Emnekode),
CONSTRAINT EksamenEmneFK FOREIGN KEY(Emnekode) REFERENCES Emne(Emnekode),
CONSTRAINT EksamenRomFK FOREIGN KEY(Romnr) REFERENCES Rom(Romnr)
);
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO Emne (Emnekode, Emnenavn, Studiepoeng) VALUES
("PRG1000", "Grunnleggende programmering 1", 7.5),
("PRG1100", "Grunnleggende programmering 2", 7.5),
("WEB1100", "Webutvikling og HCI", 7.5),
("SYS1000", "Systemutvikling", 7.5),
("ORL1100", "Organisering", 7.5);
```

```
INSERT INTO Eksamensresultat(Karakter,Studentnr,Emnekode,Dato) VALUES
("A","240202","PRG1000","20210505"),
("C","240202","PRG1100","20210506"),
("B","240202","SYS1000","20210507"),
("A","225087","PRG1100","20210506"),
(NULL,"225087","SYS1000","20210507"),
(NULL,"240225","SYS1000","20210507"),
(NULL,"884642","SYS1000","20210507"),
("C","139959","PRG1000","20210505"),
("B","240202","PRG1000","20210606");
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included schema and sample data.  Use a natural join instead of the old school (phun) `FROM Eksamensresultat, Emne
WHERE Eksamensresultat.Emnekode = Emne.Emnekode`.

Comment: Perfect, also, can you give us the expected result for the data?

Comment: I have added it now. 
Last note from my lecture at the University: "WE DO NOT USE NATURAL JOIN!!!!" Teacher told several times that we do not use that......... So I need to learn to use old style for examn even tho I know that in companies people use 'natural join'.

Comment: It is explained in the Output: link. Thats explained how I want the output. So I want only the highest result showing if the student have 1 or more result on same examn.

Comment: Eksamensresultat vs Eksamen, and you need to drop `CONSTRAINT EksamenRomFK FOREIGN KEY(Romnr) REFERENCES Rom(Romnr)` as you didn't give us that and not relevant

Comment: I want to have the same table that I had with the same columns. Only difference is that the result B is not in the table since it is lower than result A for that student.

Comment: I think you need your teacher to clarify how he defines "NATURAL JOIN!". A Natural join is normally just a special kind of join where the values you join join on are implicit. I agree that there is a reason to avoid these. But none of the joins in the answers here are natural joins.

Comment: Eksamensresultat vs Eksamen, and you need to drop CONSTRAINT EksamenRomFK FOREIGN KEY(Romnr) REFERENCES Rom(Romnr): I know. But there is more tables included that I did not post here since I'm not asking towards those tables in this specific case. 

Allan: I tried your code and got this: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Thanks for the help. But non of the askings did work.
Allan: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias
Gordon: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'er' in 'where clause'
Remember that this is also commands I will have to use in Python ot get the correct data out from mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to identify the right row:

```
SELECT Studentnr, Emnekode, min(Karakter)
FROM Eksamensresultat
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

then join that with your query to select the correct row of Eksamensresultat (only the group by column and aggregate are valid):

```
SELECT Eksamensresultat.*, Emnenavn, Studiepoeng
FROM Eksamensresultat as e
JOIN (
  SELECT Studentnr, Emnekode, min(Karakter) 'Karakter'
  FROM Eksamensresultat
  GROUP BY 1, 2
) using (Studentnr, Emnekode, Karakter)
JOIN Emne using (Emnekode)
ORDER BY RIGHT (Eksamensresultat.Emnekode, 4) ASC;
```

The other (more readable) option is to use a window function if your mysql is recent enough.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html.  I would need a working schema to test that query for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `ROW_NUMBER()`, so you can choose one row per student/exam with the higher `Karakter`:

```
SELECT er.*
FROM (SELECT er.*, e.Emnenavn, e.Studiepoeng,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY er.Studentnr, er.Emnekode ORDER BY er.Karakter DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Eksamensresultat er JOIN
           Emne e
           ON er.Emnekode = e.Emnekode 
     ) er
WHERE er = 1
ORDER BY RIGHT(Emnekode, 4) ASC;
```